# litespeed php will not generate a correctly signed request for Amazon product API, regular php works fine

Tags: php, litespeed

I've taken the below PHP code directly from Amazon's scratchpad (https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/scratchpad/index.html), where they provide boilerplate code to query their product API. I only modified it a tiny bit to show the HTTP errors - everything else is a direct copy and paste.

I put in my own credentials (access key, secret key and partner tag) and the code works perfectly on my own macOS laptop, running (regular) PHP 7.1.23.

I move the code to my personal server, and it runs perfectly, running PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26

When I move the same code to a customer's server, I get an error from Amazon that the request is not signed correctly. The error is:

```
{"__type":"com.amazon.paapi5#InvalidSignatureException","Errors":[{"Code":"InvalidSignature","Message":"The request has not been correctly signed. If you are using an AWS SDK, requests are signed for you automatically; otherwise, go to https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/sending-request.html#signing."}]}
```

On that machine, lsphp --version returns

```
PHP 7.0.27 (litespeed) (built: Jan  4 2018 16:01:06)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.27, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

The exact code, directly from Amazon is:

```
<?php

/* Copyright 2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved. */
/* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. */

// Put your Secret Key in place of **********
$serviceName="ProductAdvertisingAPI";
$region="us-east-1";
$accessKey="*****";
$secretKey="*****";
$payload="{"
        ." \"ItemIds\": ["
        ."  \"0995198918\""
        ." ],"
        ." \"Resources\": ["
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Small\","
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Medium\","
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Large\","
        ."  \"Images.Variants.Small\","
        ."  \"Images.Variants.Medium\","
        ."  \"Images.Variants.Large\""
        ." ],"
        ." \"PartnerTag\": \"*****\","
        ." \"PartnerType\": \"Associates\","
        ." \"Marketplace\": \"www.amazon.com\""
        ."}";
$host="webservices.amazon.com";
$uriPath="/paapi5/getitems";
$awsv4 = new AwsV4 ($accessKey, $secretKey);
$awsv4->setRegionName($region);
$awsv4->setServiceName($serviceName);
$awsv4->setPath ($uriPath);
$awsv4->setPayload ($payload);
$awsv4->setRequestMethod ("POST");
$awsv4->addHeader ('content-encoding', 'amz-1.0');
$awsv4->addHeader ('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
$awsv4->addHeader ('host', $host);
$awsv4->addHeader ('x-amz-target', 'com.amazon.paapi5.v1.ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.GetItems');
$headers = $awsv4->getHeaders ();
$headerString = "";
foreach ( $headers as $key => $value ) {
    $headerString .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
}
$params = array (
        'http' => array (
            'ignore_errors' => true, 
            'header' => $headerString,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $payload
        )
    );
$stream = stream_context_create ( $params );

$fp = fopen ( 'https://'.$host.$uriPath, 'rb', false, $stream );

$response = stream_get_contents ( $fp );

echo $response;

if (! $fp) {
    throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
}
$response = stream_get_contents ( $fp );
if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
}
echo $response;

class AwsV4 {

    private $accessKey = null;
    private $secretKey = null;
    private $path = null;
    private $regionName = null;
    private $serviceName = null;
    private $httpMethodName = null;
    private $queryParametes = array ();
    private $awsHeaders = array ();
    private $payload = "";

    private $HMACAlgorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
    private $aws4Request = "aws4_request";
    private $strSignedHeader = null;
    private $xAmzDate = null;
    private $currentDate = null;

    public function __construct($accessKey, $secretKey) {
        $this->accessKey = $accessKey;
        $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
        $this->xAmzDate = $this->getTimeStamp ();
        $this->currentDate = $this->getDate ();
    }

    function setPath($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    function setServiceName($serviceName) {
        $this->serviceName = $serviceName;
    }

    function setRegionName($regionName) {
        $this->regionName = $regionName;
    }

    function setPayload($payload) {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    function setRequestMethod($method) {
        $this->httpMethodName = $method;
    }

    function addHeader($headerName, $headerValue) {
        $this->awsHeaders [$headerName] = $headerValue;
    }

    private function prepareCanonicalRequest() {
        $canonicalURL = "";
        $canonicalURL .= $this->httpMethodName . "\n";
        $canonicalURL .= $this->path . "\n" . "\n";
        $signedHeaders = '';
        foreach ( $this->awsHeaders as $key => $value ) {
            $signedHeaders .= $key . ";";
            $canonicalURL .= $key . ":" . $value . "\n";
        }
        $canonicalURL .= "\n";
        $this->strSignedHeader = substr ( $signedHeaders, 0, - 1 );
        $canonicalURL .= $this->strSignedHeader . "\n";
        $canonicalURL .= $this->generateHex ( $this->payload );
        return $canonicalURL;
    }

    private function prepareStringToSign($canonicalURL) {
        $stringToSign = '';
        $stringToSign .= $this->HMACAlgorithm . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= $this->xAmzDate . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= $this->currentDate . "/" . $this->regionName . "/" . $this->serviceName . "/" . $this->aws4Request . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= $this->generateHex ( $canonicalURL );
        return $stringToSign;
    }

    private function calculateSignature($stringToSign) {
        $signatureKey = $this->getSignatureKey ( $this->secretKey, $this->currentDate, $this->regionName, $this->serviceName );
        $signature = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $stringToSign, $signatureKey, true );
        $strHexSignature = strtolower ( bin2hex ( $signature ) );
        return $strHexSignature;
    }

    public function getHeaders() {
        $this->awsHeaders ['x-amz-date'] = $this->xAmzDate;
        ksort ( $this->awsHeaders );

        // Step 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST
        $canonicalURL = $this->prepareCanonicalRequest ();

        // Step 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN
        $stringToSign = $this->prepareStringToSign ( $canonicalURL );

        // Step 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE
        $signature = $this->calculateSignature ( $stringToSign );

        // Step 4: CALCULATE AUTHORIZATION HEADER
        if ($signature) {
            $this->awsHeaders ['Authorization'] = $this->buildAuthorizationString ( $signature );
            return $this->awsHeaders;
        }
    }

    private function buildAuthorizationString($strSignature) {
        return $this->HMACAlgorithm . " " . "Credential=" . $this->accessKey . "/" . $this->getDate () . "/" . $this->regionName . "/" . $this->serviceName . "/" . $this->aws4Request . "," . "SignedHeaders=" . $this->strSignedHeader . "," . "Signature=" . $strSignature;
    }

    private function generateHex($data) {
        return strtolower ( bin2hex ( hash ( "sha256", $data, true ) ) );
    }

    private function getSignatureKey($key, $date, $regionName, $serviceName) {
        $kSecret = "AWS4" . $key;
        $kDate = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $date, $kSecret, true );
        $kRegion = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $regionName, $kDate, true );
        $kService = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $serviceName, $kRegion, true );
        $kSigning = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $this->aws4Request, $kService, true );

        return $kSigning;
    }

    private function getTimeStamp() {
        return gmdate ( "Ymd\THis\Z" );
    }

    private function getDate() {
        return gmdate ( "Ymd" );
    }
}
?>
```

What is different about the lsphp executable that prevents it from generating a correctly signed request?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but is it possible that the time on the server you've deployed to is incorrectly set?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also went down that rabbit hole, but I don't think it matters because the code is always using GMT for all the signing.

Comment: It's been a bit since I've worked with PHP in a production environment, but my understanding is that it's building the timestamp off the system time (even if it's grabbing it in GMT). As such if the server's time isn't set correctly (i.e., set 1 day in the future from the actual current date), the GMT timestamp would also be off by the same amount. However unlikely this misconfiguration is (especially given most all OS' default support for `ntp`), I have seen it happen previously where the time was set incorrectly by a sysadmin when setting the server up, & it may be worth just looking into.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. For some reason I thought that even if the server time was off the GMT time would be correct (duh).
Checking now, 'date -u' returns a time that is a full five minutes ahead of what Google says is GMT. I'm getting the server admin to correct it and will report back!

Comment: Thankyou, that was the issue and it's now working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As solved in the comments, if the server's time differs from the actual current time by any sizeable amount, the hashing function will produce an incorrect result that Amazon will reject.

Reconfigure the server to sync its clock using the network, or manually adjust to reflect the correct time so that PHP's date/time functionality begins returning the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @esqew the time on the server was off by about 5 minutes, which resulted in the GMT time also being off, and then I guess Amazon doesn't like the request.

Once we adjusted that the sample amazon code runs perfectly, and all is well with the world!

Thanks very much,